# concurrency and heavy oracle querying using yii

Tags: php, database, oracle, yii, concurrency

I am having a yii application wich also have several restfull functions, right now i am having about 50 users heavily making queries or bulk insertions, i am experiencing a total hold on the web to return model queries whenever bulk inserts so the web wont respond if a user is using the restfull with inserts or updates

the bd is in oracle 10g , the app is in yii 1.1.13

is concurrency on table querying an issue in yii-oracle or there is certain configuration to be accomplished to get it working fine with no locking or holds with concurrent queries?

the JDBC connection (squirrel or sql client) works just fine while app is held  by restfull querying so i guess it could be configuration with oci8

Comment: Oracle readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers so what you're describing doesn't seem to make sense.  Have you done anything to trace the sessions to see where the contention is coming?  Are you actually getting blocking in the database?  Or is it coming somewhere else?

Comment: thats exactly what i thought, have not been able to trace session since the dev team does not have permissions to trace the session , but i can request it nevertheless would not know where to exactly look at

Comment: I'd start with an AWR/ Statspack report from the database during a period of load to see if you're seeing a bunch of wait time in the database.  If not, the contention would have to be in the middle tier.

Comment: all right i will do that , as soon  as i get answers i will update